# Visualizing binary trees in Java and C++

Tags: java, c++, visualization

Is there any way I could visualize a binary tree in java and C++? It could be a plugin for eclipse or VC++(although I dont think a plugin would be capable) or, it could be a library that enables you to draw them. I want to do this with the minimum amount of work possible. I can do it now with C++ and Win32 but that isn't an option because it requires too much time to code the damned thing. I also know that there might not be quite a simple solution to this, but I am looking for the best possible one out there, for both languages. The BST structure I talk of here will be custom, not a library one.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think AT&T graphviz and its dot.exe is as easy as it gets to use.  You can all it from inside Java if you must.

Answer (score 2):

If you can output your binary tree in `DOT` format, it's pretty easy to visualize it. `DOT` is a super simple language which you should be able to emit in just a few lines of code. An example looks like this:

```
 digraph graphname {
     a -> b -> c;
     b -> d;
 }
```

Which generates http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/DotLanguageDirected.svg/168px-DotLanguageDirected.svg.png

Wikipedia has more: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_language

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to visualize it for debugging and are using a Unix-like operating system, you can try [ddd](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/).